# Spring boot OAuth2 - how to get info from token response, without using userInfoUri

Tags: java, spring, oauth

I've followed the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ but cannot get it to work.  The tutorial requires the OAuth service to support an endpoint configured by "userInfoUri", but the service I am trying to integrate with does not support this functionality.

The response looks something like this:

```
 {"access_token":"89f0181c-168b-4d7d-831c-1fdda2d7bbbb","token_type":"bearer", "refresh_token":"69e883f6-d84e-4ae6-87f5-ef0044e3e9a7","expires_in":631138518, "scope":"/whatever","uid":"1234","name":"Joe Bloggs"}
```

How do I extract the user name and id from the token response instead?